# Checkbox Size Xamarin Android

Tags: checkbox, xamarin.forms

I've implemented checkboxes in my Xamarin Forms App using the following article:

https://alexdunn.org/2018/04/10/xamarin-tip-build-your-own-checkbox-in-xamarin-forms/

The only issue I have is that I can't set the size of Android, there is a question in the comments section, however there is no solution.  No matter what I do the SizeRequest is always 64x64 - can anyone offer any suggestions or reason why I can't resize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I found a [possible solution](https://github.com/jboliveira/XForms.Sample.CheckBox), check the steps below:

- Add a `BindableProperty` called `SizeRequest` in the custom CheckBox control.
- Create a method `GetDefaultCheckBoxDrawable` to get the default CheckBox drawable.
- Change `OnElementChanged` method to clear and resize the text, set the width/height based on `SizeRequest`, reset the button drawable and set a new Background drawable with the default checkbox drawable.

`AndroidCheckboxRenderer.cs`:

```
private Drawable GetDefaultCheckBoxDrawable(Android.Views.View view)
{
    TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
    view.Context.Theme.ResolveAttribute(Android.Resource.Attribute.ListChoiceIndicatorMultiple, value, true);
    var origImg = view.Context.Resources.GetDrawable(value.ResourceId);
    var porterDuffColor = new Android.Graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter(Element.CheckColor.ToAndroid(), Android.Graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
    origImg.SetColorFilter(porterDuffColor);
    return origImg;
}

protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomCheckbox> e)
{
    ...

    // CheckBox displays its height from the TEXT, as well as images.
    checkBox.Text = "";
    checkBox.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Sp, 0);

    // Set the width and height based on SizeRequest
    if (Element.SizeRequest >= 0)
    {
        checkBox.SetWidth((int)Element.SizeRequest);
        checkBox.SetHeight((int)Element.SizeRequest);
    }

    // Reset the Button Drawable
    checkBox.SetButtonDrawable(null);
    // Set Background Drawable with the default CheckBox
    checkBox.SetBackgroundDrawable(GetDefaultCheckBoxDrawable(this));

    ...
}
```

Check out [my GitHub](https://github.com/jboliveira/XForms.Sample.CheckBox) for the full solution.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: This is a great response!! I updated a few lines that showed as deprecated, but apart from that it worked very well! Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, have a few lines deprecated, I will fix them as well and keep the repo up to date. tks

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use before the line 91, the code below in order to scale the control:

```
Control.ScaleX = 0.70;
Control.ScaleY = 0.70;
```

Comment: thanks for the very prompt reply - I set the ScaleX and Y to 1.5f (I want to increase the size of the checkbox), however this causes half of the checkbox to show - no matter what the alignment is